# Как передать environment из build.gradle в config.properties?

Tags: java, gradle, config, testng, environment-variables

Созданы автотесты - java+gradle+testng

Есть файл  config.properties, в котором находится

```
BASE_URL = https://api.dev.im.info.ru/
```

Наборы классов для тестов содержаться списком в xml и запускаются через task build.gradle

```
task Dev_test(type: Test) {
useTestNG() {
    options {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testngFiles/All_tests.xml'
    }
}
```

Задача такая: надо осуществить запуски на 2х разных config (пока только url разные)

```
BASE_URL = https://api.dev.im.info.ru/
BASE_URL = https://api.stage.im.info.ru/
```

Можно ли  как то задать переменную в task build.gradle

```
task Dev_test(type: Test) {
useTestNG() {
    options {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testngFiles/All_tests.xml'
    }
    environment 'url', 'dev'
}
```

}

и использовать в config.properties, что то типа -

```
BASE_URL = https://api.{{url}}.im.info.ru/
```

но так не работает. Можно как то задать переменную из build.gradle в config.properties? Или каким то друим вариантом? Задать второй config, указать путь до него по какому то признаку...
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если кому то пригодится, вот подробный пример -  https://itnext.io/how-to-run-automation-scripts-in-multiple-environments-abc39d11aa20 как сделать

Comment: как вариант, приложение должно читать properties файл, где будут его настройки, в проекте может быть неограниченное количество таких файлов, которые или возможности получения их по некоторому пути для различных нужд , и в зависисмости что запускается или какой "профиль" (prod, dev, test, preview и т.п.) в русурсы будет добавляться файл с нужными значениями

Comment: да, как раз так и сделала, спасибо